# MySQL Query with reference parameter from another table

Tags: mysql

I apologise in advance if this might seem simple as my assignment needs to be passed in 3 hours time and I don't have enough time to do some further research as I have another pending assignment to be submitted tonight. I only know the basic MYSQL commands and not these types. Please help.

Say that I have two tables:

```
   ________________     _________________
  |    customers   |   |     agents      |
  |________________|   |_________________|
  |(pk)customer id |   |(pk) agent_id    |
  |(fk) agent_id   |   |    first_name   |
  |   first_name   |   |    last_name    |
  |   last_name    |   |     address     |
  |________________|   |_________________|
```

Basically I would just like to know how to query something like: (in incorrect terms)

`SELECT * FROM customers WHERE agent_id = '(agent_id of Michael Smith from the AGENTS table)'`

obviously I only have the agent_id of the agent and i can directly call it if i know what the agents name is based on the id like:
`SELECT * FROM customers WHERE agent_id = '4'`

but how can i query it by submitting the agent first name and last name as parameter?
(first name and last name because agents can have the same names, or even same last names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember your foreign key does not help you building the query, you have to tell the database what you want in the query (however, a foreign key can help data spread across tables more consistent).

You can use a [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) here.

You can implement it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers C
INNER JOIN agents A ON C.agent_id = A.agent_id
WHERE A.last_name = 'Smith'
    AND A.first_name = 'Michael';
```

Comment: @Bjoem thanks, btw, do i still need to put as? is it required/good practise? - eg: `FROM customers as C`

Comment: Both work fine, since the mysql query parser jumps over `AS` anyway. I somehow started leaving `AS` away a few years back, maybe its faster. My coworkers never complained. So... basically, whatever's best for you.

Comment: @GitKidd - The WHERE should more properly be "WHERE agents.first_name = 'Michael' AND A.last_name = 'Smith';"

Comment: Updated. My example was to show the approach, adding other parameters in the `WHERE`-part of this statement should be no big trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a join as well.

```
select * 
from customers 
where customers.agent_id in (
    select agents.agent_id 
    from agents 
    where agents.first_name = 'Michael' and agents.last_name = 'Smith'
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Tap , btw, in terms of code optimisation, is join a much better approach than this method?

Comment: @GitKidd - In terms of optimization, yes, a join is almost always superior to a subselect like this

Comment: Yes, in practice a join would be a better option.  Just putting this one out there...